# Flask SQLAlchemy form display demo image when select image file before submitting

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having a problem where my `flask` app has an update form with a `MultiFileField` to select multiple images. The view of this form has an `image` tag to view a demo image imported from the files selected.

How can i view a demo image everytime a user select a new file without submitting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.